# Testing Spring Controller POST method after adding Spring Security on Kotlin

Tags: spring, testing, spring-security, kotlin, controller

I'm developing a Spring Boot application with Kotlin.
I recently added Spring Security as a dependency and now I'm not able to test my Controllers anymore.

This is my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users", produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE])
class UserController {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var userService: UserService

    @PostMapping
    fun addUser(@Valid @RequestBody user: User): ResponseEntity<PostUserResponse> {
        userService.addUser(user)
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(PostUserResponse())
    }

    @GetMapping("user/{login}")
    fun getUserByLogin(@PathVariable login: String): ResponseEntity<User> {
        val user = userService.getUserByLogin(login)
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(user)
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(NoSuchElementException::class)
    fun failedToRetrieveById(exception: NoSuchElementException): ResponseEntity<UserNotFoundResponse> {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(UserNotFoundResponse())
    }
}
```

And this is my test class:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = [UserController::class])
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class UserControllerTest {
    @MockBean
    private lateinit var userService: UserService

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var context: WebApplicationContext

    private lateinit var mvc : MockMvc

    val login = "test@test.test"
    val password = "password"
    val user = User(login = login, password = password)

    @BeforeAll
    fun setup () {
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .apply<DefaultMockMvcBuilder>(springSecurity())
                .build()
    }

    @Test
    fun `Sending POST to the users endpoint with a valid json creates a new user`() {
        val payload = mapOf(
                "login" to login,
                "password" to password
        )
        Mockito.`when`(userService.addUser(user))
                .thenReturn(user)


        mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/users")
                .with(csrf().asHeader())
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .content(JSONObject(payload).toString()))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isCreated)
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
    }
}
```

My code mimics the example that can be found here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#test-mockmvc-smmrpp

But still the HTTP code of the reply is 401.

It's interesting to notice that removing the line:

```
.with(csrf().asHeader())
```

Makes the server reply with a 403 instead of a 401.

My security configuration is basically "blank". I'm not specifying any restrictions so, according to the documentation the only problem should be providing a valid CSRF token.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class WebSecurityConfig : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {
    override fun configure (httpSecurity: HttpSecurity) {
        httpSecurity
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/*")
                .permitAll()
    }
}
```

How to generate a valid request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a complex question, the answer depends on your security configuration.

But in general, you should include `spring-security-test` dependency, and then [this documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/test-mockmvc.html) should help you to go further.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added my security configuration (which currently is very very basic) to the question. According to my understanding of the documentation the CSRF token thing should be the only requirement to make the request valid.

Comment: `401` means that request is made by un-authenticated user. For changing this try to add: `perform(post("/users").with(user("user")))`. This adds user to Security context and request should pass to controller.

Comment: It worked. I didn't get that you have to specify a user by default